Son heard loud bang then main electric switch on breaker switched off
After loud bang and trip in the breaker, some lights were flickering. Switched on the breaker and everything worked again except everything that was plugged into this one power strip. The power strip smelled of burnt plastic. Unplugged it all and plugged it into the wall and it all worked. Could it have been the power strip? My son was the only one awake and heard it and hes not sure where it came from.

What was plugged into the power strip?

Go unplug the burnt power strip now. It’s trashed.

Any interesting weather at the time(lighting)?  How long have you been using the power strip before it burnt up?

Was son playing with pointy metal things at the time something mysteriously went bang?

@SimonB You've just brought back a memory. When I was 10 or so, I wrapped enamelled wire around the three pins of a UK plug, obviusly hard enough to break some of the insulation and plugged it in .There was a big flash and bang, the house went dark, and the next thing I heard was my dad coming up the hall to my room to see what was up (the fuse board was in a cupboard in my room).
I seem to remember him being surprisingly relaxed about it.

It certainly could have been the power strip. It may have been an electrical short, which can sometimes make loud bangs, and cleared itself when vaporized metal created by the short flew away. The power strip should not be used again unless/until the insides have been checked out by a qualified person.
